# If I purchase a game on a Steam account, can I play that game on a second account?

Tags: steam

If you are confused i will clear it up...

**Account 1** (mine) I purchased --> *Left 4 Dead*

Then I made a new account,

**Account 2** (also mine) I didn't purchase anything yet.

Can I play *Left 4 Dead* with account 2?

Comment: No. You haven't bought L4D on Account 2.

Comment: @Frank No, steam family sharing will allow this.

Comment: The short answer would be "Different accounts are assumed to be different people, just because you happen to hold two doesn't mean they'll be treated differently."

Answer (score 23):

Yes and no.  Game licenses are tied to an account, so your new account will not own the game.

However, using [Steam Family Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing), you can set up your new account to play games from your old account.  Once that is set up, **yes, you will be able to play Left 4 Dead from your new account** on that computer.

Note that this will not allow you to use one copy of Left 4 Dead to play with two people. Only one person can be playing games from the old account at a time.  You also need to keep access to the old account so you can set family sharing up again on any future computers.

Comment: For the record, not all games work with Steam Family Sharing (although it's a very small amount, iirc around 15). L4D2 is a game that works.

Comment: @Chipperyman - it must be opt-in for the publishers. I can't imagine the games having problems with it. Perhaps an inability/lack of interest in changing some archaic wording in a terms of agreement somewhere

Comment: I think it has to do with third-party DRM.

Comment: @Chipperyman: There are also some games that do not have 3rd party DRM, but don't work with family sharing anyways.  [Planetary Annihilation](http://store.steampowered.com/app/233250/) is the only one I know of.